# \cleardoublepage does not seem to work

Tags: page-breaking

I have tried to use the \cleardoublepage command so that each chapter starts on a right hand page. However, the command does not seem to work. I have included a minimalistic excerpt of the set-up in Latex. I have also tried to include operinright in the documentclass entry, but the chapters still do not start on a right hand page.

The output is: http://www.filedropper.com/test2_6

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper,openright]{report}
\begin{document}

\cleardoublepage
\input{chapter1}
\cleardoublepage
\input{chapter1}
\cleardoublepage
\input{chapter1}
\cleardoublepage


\end{document}
```

where chapter 1 is:

```
\chapter{Test}

This is chapter 1
```

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add the `twoside` parameter. One a one-sided document, which is the default for the report-class, leaving empty pages would just be confusing.

**Code**

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside]{report}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}

\cleardoublepage
\lipsum[1]
\cleardoublepage
\lipsum[2]
\cleardoublepage
\lipsum[3]
\cleardoublepage


\end{document}
```

Comment: If a chapter end in the left side (for document class, a4paper, 12pt, two side option), then in that case, `\cleardopublepage` is not working. How to fix this??