# Adding (not removing) blank pages onside

Tags: xetex, double-sided, blank-page, single-sided

There are tons of questions about removing blank pages from `twoside` documents, e.g. theses.  However, there are a lot fewer about *adding* blank pages (or pages with a header only) that aren't simply solved by using `twoside`.

I'd like to add (numbered) pages at certain spots in a `oneside` document with class `book` - essentially, to emulate the same page numbering from `twoside` but without the change in margins which makes viewing such a document on a device a pain.  (I would like to physically print the `twoside` version and want both versions to have the same numbering.  I don't mind extra pages.)  It seems that `cleardoublepage` is *not* what I want since according to any documentation I can find, it only adds the extra page in `twoside` mode.  I'm okay with this not being automatic - I only have to add them at the end of chapters, after all.  Does anyone know if this is possible without extreme hacking of things like the `geometry` package?

Possibly related questions that didn't seem to answer my question:

- [After adding blank page, two sided option has confused](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/324841/after-adding-blank-page-two-sided-option-has-confused) (but this is in `twoside`)
- [\cleardoublepage does not seem to work](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/316208/cleardoublepage-does-not-seem-to-work) (self explanatory, and answer recommends `twoside`)
- [How do I make the first page double sided in a single sided LaTeX document?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42252/how-do-i-make-the-first-page-double-sided-in-a-single-sided-latex-document) (I don't want to switch the layout, just to have consistent page numbering)

Ironically, apparently [this bug](https://github.com/Tufte-LaTeX/tufte-latex/issues/135) in one package is sort of exactly what I am looking for ... but I don't use that package and don't want to rely on a bug!

Final note, just in case it would make a difference: I am using `xelatex` and cannot easily switch to `pdflatex`.

Comment: As a start, try redefining `\cleardoublepage` ignore any consideration of whether or not you're in `twoside` mode: `\makeatletter \def\cleardoublepage{\clearpage \ifodd\c@page\else\hbox{}\newpage\if@twocolumn\hbox{}\newpage\fi\fi}\makeatother`. The definition of `\cleardoublepage` was taken from [`latex.ltx`](https://www.tug.org/svn/texlive/trunk/Master/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/latex.ltx?view=co).

Comment: If you know exactly where the page breaks before you want a blank page (with header), you can insert this: `<blank line>\clearpage \mbox{ } \clearpage`.  If you want the blank page inserted after the current page is complete, it's not quite so simple, and I'd have to experument.

Comment: What `\documentclass` are you using?

Comment: @Werner I think I mentioned it was `book`.  I figure that might make a difference?

Comment: @barbarabeeton that sounds like something I could try.  Basically, I have discrete chapters that in `twoside` always start on the right page (appropriately) but I'd like the numbering in `oneside` to be the same, so I think I can just try adding your suggestion after each one - or the one in the answer.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following minimal example updates the default `\cleardoublepage` (only when not in `twoside` mode) to completely ignore the `twoside` option as part of its conditioning mechanism.

```
%\documentclass[twoside]{book}
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\makeatletter
% Update \cleardoublepage to be similar in oneside and twoside
\if@twoside\else
  \def\cleardoublepage{%
    \clearpage
    \ifodd\c@page\else
      \hbox{}\newpage
      \if@twocolumn
        \hbox{}\newpage
      \fi
    \fi
  }
\fi
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    
\tableofcontents

\sloppy
\chapter{First chapter}
\lipsum[1-45]

\chapter{Second chapter}
\lipsum[1-50]

\chapter{Third chapter}
\lipsum[1-50]

\end{document}
```

You could also try this (re)definition of `\cleardoublepage`:

```
\let\oldcleardoublepage\cleardoublepage
\renewcommand{\cleardoublepage}{{%
  \@twosidetrue% Force twoside mode temporarily
  \oldcleardoublepage
}}
```

Comment: This is going to be by far the easiest to implement - I have a place to add macros for exactly this kind of thing, and the results were perfect with extremely minimal editing.  Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

`\newpage\null` will produce a blank page.

For example
this code will produce a book `twoside` with, as expected, chapters starting in odd pages:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside]{book}

\usepackage{kantlipsum} %dummy text

\begin{document}
    
\tableofcontents
    
\chapter{One}
1. \kant[1-3]

\chapter{Two}
5. \kant[5-9]   

\chapter{Three}
11. \kant[11-15]        
    
\end{document}
```

Adding blank pages in the appropriate places, this will produced the same TOC with `oneside`

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside]{book}

\usepackage{kantlipsum} %dummy text

\begin{document}
    
\tableofcontents

\newpage\null % add a blank page
\chapter{One}
1. \kant[1-3]

\chapter{Two}
5. \kant[5-9]   

\newpage\null   % add another blank page
\chapter{Three}
11. \kant[11-15]        
    
\end{document}
```

Two side, chapter in odd pages, book margins

[image: 2d]

On side, some chapters in even pages, e.g. the first chapter starts  immediately after the TOC, on page 2.

[image: 1s]

One side with 2 added pages. Now all chapters start on even pages, with equal margins.

[image: 1s af]

It might be useful to add  `\newpage\null\thispagestyle{plain}`, when creating a blank page, or `\newpage\null\thispagestyle{empty}` to suppress all the headers.

Notes

(1) With `twoside` it is easy to have the same margin on odd and even pages with `\setlength{\evensidemargin}{\oddsidemargin}` before `\begin{document}`

(2) Still, it is sometimes necessary to create blank pages in a book using `\newpage\null\thispagestyle{empty}`

(3) `\null` is the same as `\hbox{}`.

Comment: Thanks, I'll have to try that later.  This is a model explanation - the MWE is just long enough to be interesting, and the images make it very clear what to expect.  If I was very snazzy I might even have to put "this page intentionally left blank" but probably I'll just see which page style the `twoside` has.  (The LaTeX is auto-generated by another program, so I am having to hand-edit it for things like this.)

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to manually add blank pages, but rather to have the same margins on either side, which can be easily obtained with `geometry`.

With the same code as in [Simon's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/578901/4427),

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[hratio=1:1,textwidth=345pt]{geometry}

\usepackage{kantlipsum} %dummy text

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{One}
1. \kant[1-3]

\chapter{Two}
5. \kant[5-9]

\chapter{Three}
11. \kant[11-15]

\end{document}
```

you will see the blank page automatically generated. The magic dimension 345pt is the usual size in the `book` class. Change it to suit your taste.

[image]

If you want some gutter, you can do as follows:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside]{book}
\usepackage{layout}

\usepackage{geometry}

\dimen0=\dimexpr(\paperwidth-345pt)/2\relax
\geometry{
  bindingoffset=7mm,
  inner=\dimexpr\dimen0-7mm\relax,
  textwidth=345pt,
}

\usepackage{kantlipsum} %dummy text

\begin{document}

\layout

\tableofcontents

\chapter{One}
1. \kant[1-3]

\chapter{Two}
5. \kant[5-9]

\chapter{Three}
11. \kant[11-15]

\end{document}
```

I added `\layout` to better show what's happening. Fix the lengths to suit your needs.

Comment: Actually, I really do want the "two-sided" margins for the two-sided version, so that when it prints and is bound there is enough gutter for that.  Otherwise I'd just print out the one-sided version as I have in the past.

Comment: @kcrisman You can use the `bindingoffset` option.

Comment: Would using that simply replicate the `twoside` option?

Comment: @kcrisman I added how to do it.